# Regex: target and partially replace

Tags: c#, regex, replace

I'm trying to remove spaces between some characters in my string:

```
element 1  : 200  :2   1 2 3 4    - 30        node 1:39
```

to

```
element 1:200:2   1 2 3 4    -30        node 1:39
```

The removed spaces were between numbers and containing `:` or between a `-` and a number.
So far I've come to this regex that targets the space between the numbers and contains `:` or `-`.

```
Regex mySpace = new Regex(@"\W+ (:|-) +");
```

What I would like to do next is to remove the spaces in those matches. How could I do that? 
Maybe with some more complex Regex that matches only the desired spaces directly and then replace them for an empty string?

Comment: Please add a tag for the language you're using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below regex would match exactly the spaces between the numbers which is delimited by `:` or spaces after the `-` upto the first number. Just replace  the matched spaces with an empty string.

```
(?<=\d)\s*(?=:)|(?<=:)\s+|(?<=-)\s+(?=\d)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/fU5qN2/1)

Your C# code would be,

```
string pattern = @"(?<=\d)\s*(?=:)|(?<=:)\s+|(?<=-)\s+(?=\d)";
string test = Regex.Replace("element 1 : 200 :2 1 2 3 4 - 30        node 1:39", pattern, "");
Console.WriteLine(test);
Console.ReadLine();
```

**Output:**

```
element 1:200:2   1 2 3 4    -30        node 1:39
```

[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/oGO9sx)

**Explanation:**

- `(?<=\d)\s*(?=:)` Match the spaces after a number which is followed by `:`
- `|` Logical OR operator.
- `(?<=:)\s+` Matches one or more spaces which are after to a `:`
- `|` Logical OR operator.
- `(?<=-)\s+(?=\d)` Matches one or more spaces just after to a  `-` followed by a number.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use your own regex, you can use groups in the replace part. Your regex captures the colon or dash in a group as it is in a parentese.
So you can replace the match with only the group (and thereby removing the whitespaces) by using $1:

```
Regex mySpace = new Regex(@"\W+ (:|-) +");
mySpace.Replace(yourtext, "$1")
```

(if you had several groups your could use $1, $2, etc.)

The answer from Avinash Raj is more sophisticated but maybe this is easier for you to read afterwards.